# subset rows in data frame using a list of characters

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I would like to subset all the rows in iris data frame where the Species is setosa and versicolor and to keep the dataframe format..

P.S: I would prefer to not convert this vector into numeric, if possible.

Comment: `subiris <- iris[iris$Species == "setosa" | iris$Species == "versicolor", ]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.  I prefer `grepl`, since it shortens the call quite a bit.

```
> iris[grepl("setosa|versicolor", iris$Species), ]
```

Or even better, for this example since there are only three levels of `Species`, is

```
> iris[!grepl("virginica", iris$Species), ]
```

And `%in%` will also match a "table" of strings

```
> iris[iris$Species %in% c("setosa", "versicolor"), ]
```